# Creating a nested object from entries

Tags: javascript, json, object, serialization, deserialization

Is there a way to generate a nested JavaScript `Object` from entries?

`Object.fromEntries()` doesn't quite do it since it doesn't do nested objects.

```js
const entries = [['a.b', 'c'], ['a.d', 'e']]

// Object.fromEntries(entries) returns:
{
    'a.b': 'c',
    'a.d': 'e',
}

// whatIAmLookingFor(entries) returns:
{
    a: {
        b: 'c',
        d: 'e',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reduce the array `entries` and reduce the keys as well. Then assign the value to the  final object with the last key.

```js
const
    setValue = (object, [key, value]) => {
        const
            keys = key.split('.'),
            last = keys.pop();
        keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, object)[last] = value;
        return object;
    },
    entries = [['a.b', 'c'], ['a.d', 'e']],
    result = entries.reduce(setValue, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: chaotically beautiful

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way using `lodash`:

```js
import set from 'lodash/set'

const result = {}
const entries = [['a.b', 'c'], ['a.d', 'e']]

entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const key = entry[0]
    const value = entry[1]
    set(result, key, value)
})
```